# How to visulaize a plot having X,Y as 2-Dimensional Arrays using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have 2, 2-Dimensional Arrays X, Y

```
X =
[[ 2.5   2.5 ]
 [ 4.   -1.  ]
 [ 1.   -4.  ]
 [ 3.    1.25]
 [ 2.    4.  ]
 [ 1.    5.  ]]
```

and corrosponding value of Y are :

```
Y = 
[[0.676523   0.24676648]
 [0.7425371  0.67469769]
 [0.60264056 0.90981004]
 [0.69950841 0.38773426]
 [0.65265244 0.12933664]
 [0.60264056 0.08060863]]
```

what is best possible way to visualize a plot X,Y using Matplotlib

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevanttags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want each entry from X and Y paired together, your first point would be (2.5,0.676523), ... and so on, then you use the scatter() method in matplotlib with X as the first parameter, and Y as the second parameter. Two of your points are identical so there will be 11 points visible on the plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [[ 2.5, 2.5],
 [ 4.,   -1.  ],
 [ 1.,   -4.  ],
 [ 3.,    1.25],
 [ 2.,    4.  ],
 [ 1.,    5.  ]]

Y = [[0.676523,   0.24676648],
 [0.7425371,  0.67469769],
 [0.60264056, 0.90981004],
 [0.69950841, 0.38773426],
 [0.65265244, 0.12933664],
 [0.60264056, 0.08060863]]

plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: XY scatter]